# Should the setter of a property for an entity model class be set to private?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

As the primary key `PassageId` will be created automatically and cannot be changed, exposing the setter of `PassageId` does not make sense (at least to me). Should the setter of `PassageId` be set to  private?

```
public class Passage
{
    public int PassageId { get; private set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedUtc { get; private set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedUtc { get; private set; }
}
```

## Note

Most tutorials I read, the authors always use the default properties generated by Visual Studio's shortcut `prop` enter (twice) producing something like

```
public type PropertyName {get; set;}
```

So I am wondering why they didn't make the setter private.

Comment: after you run an insert, the id is updated in your local model. It could not do that without access to it. Did you try?

Comment: @Crowcoder: Thanks for your comment. I will make a try.

Comment: Yes, but not always. It really depends on how you're planning on controlling your IDs in the database. If you aren't marking that column as an Identity column, you might want control over inserting your own Id (say GUID for example).

Comment: @RizJa: By default convention it is always created as an identity, right?

Comment: @優しいエイリアン If the type is int and the column name is "Id" (not sure about "ID"), then it is created as an identity column by default. Otherwise you can use the fluent api or data annotations (i.e. [Key]) to set the column as an identity column.

Answer (score 1):

This is because usually (design-wise), the entity is an object that you will pass around for displaying data or updating it.

Therefore, when the entity is instantiated, you need to populate the properties with the data from storage (or from the presentation layer's input).

E.g. `Person person = PersonService.GetById(personId);`

Given that the PersonService calls through to the Entity Framework and finds the single Person record where the Id matches personId, it will then populate that 'person' entity with the values retrieved.

For Entity Framework to populate the entity the fields need to be publicly settable.

If via code or user input, the person's name is changed, the Id will be used on the SaveChanges() method for the update.

When inspecting an entity's properties:

If the Id is 0, then it will be treated as a new entity and should be 'Added' to storage on SaveChanges().

If the Id is > 0 then it should be Updated on SaveChanges().

If the Id field was to be set privately, after populating the rest of the properties, the class would then need a way (internally) to get the Id of the current entity from elsewhere - wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need to manually set the `Id` while it will be automatically generated by the DBMS?

Comment: You won't need to - Entity Framework will populate the Id from the one it retrieves from storage. But it won't be able to if you only have a private setter.

Comment: Hmm... I thought the framework has full access even to the private members. But after knowing that EF also be the client of our model, encapsulation principle (such as hiding some members to other clients) becomes impossible. It looks like EF does not encourge us to adopt encapsulation principle strictly.

Comment: You are on the right lines, encapsulation is a good thing, however, if you want some other code to populate an entity that you have, or for it to instantiate an entity and then populate it before passing it back to you complete; it needs access to the properties etc. Think of it like it is another part of your own code base, you pass an object to be filled with data by another method - it will need to have access to the properties.

Comment: You could have as many private properties as you wish in that entity - as long as they are not needed to support the model's storage externally.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't correct. As @優しいエイリアン says, EF can (and will) set private properties.

Comment: You would need to jump through hoops if the properties are private and you want them persisted by EF. You would at least need to use the fluent API to let EF map the properties while preventing outside code from accessing them. I was trying to keep it straight forward, we all know how virtually everything can be overridden...

Comment: I don't know if this is in response to my comment, but your claim *for Entity Framework to populate the entity the fields need to be publicly settable.* is not correct. That's all. Private setters for identity properties or calculated properties would make perfect sense. So would internal setters for the rest in certain scenario's. But I understand why the EF tools don't generate them as such *a priori*.

Comment: @GertArnold - I agree, if I worded it like it is in stone and the only way for EF to set properties - I apologise - wasn't meant that way. The code from OP wouldn't work without extra code to give EF access - so I kept with that line.